# Прокси в PHP

Tags: прокси, php, сокет

Ребят, нужна помощь. У хостера отключена curl, как можно подключиться с другому сайту через прокси? (кроме анонимайзеров). Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Вручную через [сокеты](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#82586), либо с использованием соответствующего [контекста](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.server.ru:8080', 
        'request_fulluri' => True,
        ),
    );
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$sFile = file_get_contents("http://другой.сайт.ру/", False, $cxContext);

echo $sFile;
```

как то так

Answer (score 0):

Может быть проще посмотреть, что есть у хостера? А еще лучше попросить включить или подсказать чем можно заменить.

Answer (score 0):

или как вариант - запуск wget, вряд ли он отсутствует на сервере

```
$a=`wget -O- 'https://superuser.com/'`
```

но да, плюсую обращение к тех. поддержке провайдера для включения curl